# Grep syntax - words have to end with ] if they start with [, all ^ followed by I or B

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I am checking that my subtitle files have the correct formatting.
There are 3 common errors I am looking for.

1. timestamps of the format "[00:01:22:00]" - sometimes the matching ] is forgotten. So I want to check that if "[" occurs on a line, it has exactly 11 chars of the format above and then a matching "]" The common error is the lack of a matching ]
2. Bold and Italics - If ^B or ^I occur on a line, it has to have a matching ^B or ^I in the same line.
3. If ^ occurs on a line, it has to be followed by I or B

Comment: How do you want the output? Lines which violate these rules, or a count or file name or...?

Comment: Tell us what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

A regex which does all those:

```
^(.*\[(?![0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\]).*|.*\^(?![BI]).*|([^\^\n]*\^[^B\n])*[^\^\n]*\^B([^\^\n]*\^[^B\n])*[^\^\n]*|([^\^\n]*\^[^I\n])*[^\^\n]*\^I([^\^\n]*\^[^I\n])*[^\^\n]*)$
```

Just type that into the search bar of a regex enabled text editor and it will find any erroneous lines as defined in your question.

I tested it using the find feature of both Notepad++ (Windows) and TextWrangler (Mac). It should also work with Python, or any other Regex flavor that supports negative lookaheads. When you search, make sure the check box or circle next to "regular expression" or "grep" is checked. Note that this regex will *not* work with Linux grep, because grep doesn't support lookarounds.

It's definitely not pretty, but it's really just 4 smaller regexes pushed together like `^(rule1|rule2|rule3B|rule3I)$`.

The first rule is:

```
^.*\[(?![0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\]).*$
```

which matches any line that has a "[" that isn't part of the [00:00:00:00] pattern, using a negative lookahead.

The second rule is:

```
^.*\^(?![BI]).*$
```

which matches any line with a "^" not immediately followed by a B or an I, again using a negative lookahead so that it will match at the end of the line, too.

The third rule is a doozie:

```
^([^\^\n]*\^[^B\n])*[^\^\n]*\^B([^\^\n]*\^[^B\n])*[^\^\n]*$
```

which matches any line with exactly one instance of the literal `^B` used for bold. The `([^\^\n]*\^[^B\n])*[^\^\n]*` part matches anything that isn't `^B`, and the `\^B` part matches `^B`. I've included `\n` to prevent multiline matching in notepad++. You can remove the `\n`'s if you're using grep or any program already doing a line-by-line regex search.

The fourth rule is just the third rule with "I" instead of "B".

Comment: The first rule ^.*\[(?![0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\]).*$ matches all timecodes. How can it be modified to match cases that do Not have [ followed by a matching ]

Comment: TC uses . for ms - so the correct first rule is ^.*\[(?![0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]\]).*$

Comment: For any [ not followed eventually by ], use `^.*\[(?![^\n]*\]).*$`.  To use . for ms, use `^.*\[(?![0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\]).*$`. I also limited the range of seconds and minutes here, since I wasn't sure which ones were seconds and minutes in the original post, where all separators were :.

Comment: The second rule - ^.*\^(?![BI]).*$ works perfectly using grep within text wrangler. However, when I use grep '^.*\^(?![BI]).*$' *.txt it does not work. Even \^(?![BI]) works in Text Wrangler but not from the shell. Any ideas ?

Comment: The `(?!foo)` syntax, called a negative lookahead, does not work with grep, because grep's regex engine has no lookaround support. `.*\^[^BI].*|.*\^` is functionally identical for rule 2, and should work with grep.

Comment: What would rule 1 be without lookahead ? Sorry, I tried to figure it out myself for an hour, but I am completely lost.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do rule #1 w/o a lookaround. You could do a more simplistic rule where you just look for a [ without a subsequent ], which would be `^.*\[[^\]\n]*$`, but matching a "not this pattern" type of question is going to be more difficult.